# Google Apps Script: YouTube watchHistory

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get the Users watch history of YouTube. This is what I have so far:

```
function readLatestMovies() {
  var results = YouTube.Channels.list('contentDetails', {mine: true});
  Logger.log(results);
}
```

In the logger I get the following response:

> [16-04-21 20:01:17:467 CEST] {kind=youtube#channelListResponse,
>   pageInfo={totalResults=1, resultsPerPage=1},
>   etag="dj7Wjtujr8JpxjNVWXy19qVsBRI/9D_cSFBT_DW00BBlOmm4X-jyEHU",
>   items=[{kind=youtube#channel,
>   etag="dj7Wjtujr8JpxjNVWXy19qVsBRI/A_CrD02UoyPA7qPATfqaeKRauW4",
>   id=UCUI8-QMlqUsrpDB9ECPXZng,
>   contentDetails={relatedPlaylists={favorites=FLUI8-QMlqUsrpDB9ECPXZng,
>   watchHistory=HLUI8-QMlqUsrpDB9ECPXZng,
>   watchLater=WLUI8-QMlqUsrpDB9ECPXZng, uploads=UUUI8-QMlqUsrpDB9ECPXZng,
>   likes=LLUI8-QMlqUsrpDB9ECPXZng}}}]}

So there is the *watchHistory=HLUI8-QMlqUsrpDB9ECPXZng*.
So my question is: how do I ACTUALLY get the history that seems to be hidden in the variable results?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please don't make double posts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776257/google-apps-script-get-youtube-history-of-current-user

Answer (score 2):

The id `HLUI8-QMlqUsrpDB9ECPXZng` is a playlistId. To get the history of your channel you need two step :

**First**, get the playlistId with resource `channel.list` like you did :

```
function readLatestMovies() {

  var results = YouTube.Channels.list('contentDetails', {mine: true});
  Logger.log(results);

}
```

More infos : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

**Second**, use the ressource `playlistItems.list` to get all the videos from the playlist

```
function PLaylistHistory() {
  var results = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {playlistId: 'HLUI8-QMlqUsrpDB9ECPXZng'});
  Logger.log(results);
}
```

More infos : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

Of course you need to be authenticated to get this playlist :)